# Building index for specific value

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table that keeps inventory information for products in stores on daily basis. It is like:

```
|------------|-----------|---------|-----------------|
|    Date    | ProductId | StoreId | InventoryOnHand |
|------------|-----------|---------|-----------------|
| 2017-10-11 |    348    |   121   |        2        |
| 2017-10-11 |    110    |   200   |        0        |
| 2017-10-11 |    254    |   587   |       -2        |
| 2017-10-12 |    311    |   875   |       26        |
| 2017-10-12 |    954    |   364   |       15        |
| 2017-10-12 |    348    |   121   |        0        |
| 2017-10-12 |    441    |   121   |        7        |
|     .      |     .     |    .    |        .        |
|     .      |     .     |    .    |        .        |
|     .      |     .     |    .    |        .        |
|------------|-----------|---------|-----------------|
```

In most queries I used have condition like `WHERE InventoryOnHand > 0`. I need to speed up these queries.
Therefore, I want to build and index that separates values on column `InventoryOnHand` whether they are greater than 0 or not.

Filtered Index does not solve my problem because if I use filtered index all values greater than 0 will be indexed and this increases index size. I only need to know if a value greater than 0 or not.

i.e. I want to build an index that only works when condition is `InventoryOnHand > 0`. Is there any way to do this on SQL-Server?

Comment: [Persisted Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table)? and [Computed column indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns)

Comment: I don't quite understand when you say that if you use a filtered index then all values greater than 0 will be indexed. If the index key columns and included columns don't include the `InventoryOnHand` column then that column will not take space in the index.

Comment: @xQbert your suggestion seems good, I will try it. After my tests, I will update here.

Comment: @xQbert computed column increased data space too much when persisted. May be adding a real (bit) column can help in my case but it will cause extra work on ETL side for me.

Comment: a 0/1 column has very "low cardinality" (not many different values) and indexing columns of this nature are not guaranteed to speed-up your queries.